# How to add an onTabListener for a tab in Android

Tags: android

I have an issue in my application.  The issue is that I cannot switch between activities from one tab to another.  Here is my code:

```
     public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            String n = tab.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (n =="Converter") {
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity"));
                }
            if (n =="Currencies") {
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.currencyconverter.FirstActivity"));  
            if (n=="News") {
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.currencyconverter.FirstActivity"));  
                  }
                }

        }
```

My app is crashing.  What is the issue?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not compare string like C#

In Java it is

```
if(n.equals("Converter"))
{   /// do something }
```

Comment: Some more info about comparisons in Java: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your String comparisons to use equals and your

`startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity"));`

to

`startActivity(new Intent (this, MainActivity.class));`